# tensorflow: initialization of variables inside function

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Newbee to tensorflow. I'm trying to write some simple net with following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow.contrib as tfc
import tensorflow.contrib.layers as tfcl

def generator_deconv(z, kernel):
    with tf.variable_scope("generator", reuse=True):
        weights = tf.get_variable("weights")
        biases = tf.get_variable("biases")
        result = tf.matmul(z, weights)
        result = tf.add(result, biases)
        result = tf.reshape(result, tf.stack([tf.shape(result)[0],13,4,1]))
        result = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(result, kernel, 
                output_shape=[tf.shape(result)[0],25,8,1], 
                strides=[1,2,2,1], 
                padding="SAME")
        result = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(result, kernel, 
                output_shape=[tf.shape(result)[0],50,15,1], 
                strides=[1,2,2,1], 
                padding="SAME")
        result = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(result, kernel, 
                output_shape=[tf.shape(result)[0],100,30,1], 
                strides=[1,2,2,1], 
                padding="SAME")    
        return result

kernel = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[4,4,1,1])
protype = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[3,4])
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True

with tf.variable_scope("generator"):
    t1 = tf.get_variable("weights",shape=[4,52])
    t2 = tf.get_variable("biases", shape=[52])

test = generator_deconv(protype,kernel)

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(tf.shape(t1))
    sess.run(tf.shape(t2))
    sess.run(tf.shape(test))
```

but got error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:
>   Attempting to use uninitialized value generator/weights

for the **last line**

```
sess.run(tf.shape(test))
```

checked official api of tensorflow but still don't know what's wrong with the code.

================================UPDATE==========================

found 2 ways to fix it

1.if replace

```
sess.run(init)
```

by

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

then whole code works.

OR

2.run

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(tf.shape(t1))
    sess.run(tf.shape(t2))
    sess.run(tf.shape(test))
```

again it also works.

BUT don't understand why

Answer (score 2):

I removed some parts of the code for you:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.variable_scope("generator"):
    t1 = tf.get_variable("weights",shape=[4,52])
    t2 = tf.get_variable("biases", shape=[52])

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(tf.shape(t1))
```

You add variables to your graph after you saved the result of calling global_variables_initializer(). In your fix you call this function AFTER you added all variables you want to initialize to your graph, and thus everything is initialized.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx so much for the answer! But I'm still confused. The error comes for the last line: **sess.run(tf.shape(test))**, where I tried to reuse variables "**generator/weights**". I thought it was defined by **t1** before sess and is called after initialization. Also, why change **sess.run(init)** to **sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())** can fix it if it's due to wrong order.